# How to run ESC Brushless Motor on raspberry Pi using Python?

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, motordriver

I am a very new to raspberry pi and hardware. I am trying to spin a brushless motor with ESC. below is the code (taken from a youtube video) that spins the motor till 9 and then slows it down till 4. but I want to run the motor without loops and without changing the duty cycles. Means when i run the program the motor should spin and when i stop the program the motor should stop spinning. Please update the below code.

*Sorry for my bad English. I hope I am clear what I need.*

Below is the code that I have taken from a video.

**Code:**

```
p = GPIO.PWM(7, 50)

p.start(0)
print ("starting 0")
time.sleep(3)

p.ChangeDutyCycle(3)
print("start")
time.sleep(5)



while True:
    i = 4
    while i<10:
        
        print(i)
        p.ChangeDutyCycle(i)
        time.sleep(.05)
        i +=.02
    
    while i>4:
        print(i)
        p.ChangeDutyCycle(i)
        time.sleep(.05)
        i -=.05
```

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming the motor you want to control is a brushed DC motor and not a brushless, otherwise you would need a driver between the RPI and the motor.
For a Brushed DC motor, you control the speed of the motor by changing the duty cycle of the PWM output. If you don't want to change the speed, simply set a dutycycle and stay with it.
Check this example based on https://sourceforge.net/p/raspberry-gpio-python/wiki/PWM/:

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD)
GPIO.setup(7, GPIO.OUT)

p = GPIO.PWM(7, 50)
p.start(10)
input('Press return to stop:') 
p.stop()
GPIO.cleanup()
```

Here we are using GPIO 7 with a switching frequency of 50Hz and 10% of dutycycle. Adjust the values to suit your needs.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But it didn't worked. I run the code but the motor starts beeping and nothing happens.

Comment: First check if you are using the right pin. GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD) means you are using the pin numbers instead of GPIO numbers. Check this [article](https://www.raspberrypi-spy.co.uk/2012/06/simple-guide-to-the-rpi-gpio-header-and-pins/#prettyPhoto). To change to GPIO numbering, set GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM) instead. In my answer I made a mistake by saying we're using GPIO 7. Instead I should have said pin 7 which matches different GPIO according to your RPI model. The best way to check it is by using a multimeter.

Comment: Then try an hardware PWM output such as GPIO12. Not all the GPIO pins are hardware PWM. In this case, set GPIO mode to BCM and then set p=GPIO.PWM(12,50).

Comment: @MDSulaiman in order to receive any help you need to provide more information than that.  What is not working? Do you have voltage in the expected pin and the motor still doesn't spin or do you don't have voltage at all? I haven't said this before, but it is a relevant point, the raspberry pi outputs are only capable of directly driving very small motors since they output a 3.3V with only a few milliamps.